What does Stevens mean using ''his'' instead of ''your'' in The remains of the Day?
In The Remains of the Day by Kazuo Ishiguro, when Stevens was told to inform his father William Stevens that he would reduce duties after his father's fall, I noticed he addressed his father by the third-person pronoun "his" rather than the second-person pronoun "your".
And it may be worth mentioning that when his father was dying, Stevens did say, "I'm glad you are felling much better".
I am not a native speaker. So I wonder what this means? Is it showing Stevens deliberately distanced himself from his father, even though he loved him, that he wanted to show professionalism in front of other people including/especially his father whom he thought was a great butler?

Could you give us the exact quote?

I couldn't find any cases where Stevens addresses his father as "his". He does, however, address his father as "Father" in the third person, for example, "I'm glad Father is feeling so much better". Could you correct the question, please? It would help if you could follow Peter Shor's advice and quote the passage you are asking about.
